# Huawei Cloud DB kotlin language support

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

On Cloud Db after creating table we have option to export java file which is kind of model class, if I am writting my code in kotlin can i convert that file in kotlin?? and if i want to add an extra varaiable with getter and setter can i add in the exported java class?

Answer (score 0):

The currently exported Java file can be used directly in the Kotlin project, You can use the exported java file directly in the kotlin project.

Answer (score 0):

1. The currently exported Java file can be used directly in the Kotlin project, You can use the exported java file directly in the kotlin project.
2. The exported java file does not need to be converted into kotlin language and can be used directly in kotlin project. Please refer to below screenshots. The red rectangle table java file can be used directly in Kotlin project.

[image]

3. In addition, the getter and setter methods have been configured in the exported java file and have a strong correspondence with the CloudDB type created on the cloud side. It is not recommended or supported to add and modify by yourself.